# How EXACTLY is Slick's SimpleLiteral used?

Tags: scala, slick

I want to use some extra features of **PostgreSQL** in my code but I don't want to fill the place with **SQL** string **interpolations**.

Currently I have:

```
/** Use 'now()' through Slick. */
val psqlNow = SimpleFunction.nullary[java.sql.Date]("now")

//Not really my code, but we only care for 2 lines.
def aQuery(limiter: Column[Int]) = {
  myTable
    .filter(_.validFrom >= psqlNow)
    .filter(_.validUntil <= psqlNow)
    .filter(_.fakeId === limiter).map(e => (e.fakeId, e.name)
}
```

But I want to use **'CURRENT_DATE'**, which I is a literal (and using it in place of **"now"** **throws an exception**). Can someone provide an actual example, because I can't get this to compile:

```
/** Use 'CURRENT_DATE' through Slick. */
val psqlNow = SimpleLiteral("CURRENT_DATE")(...WHAT GOES HERE?...)

//Not really my code, but we only care for 2 lines.
def aQuery(limiter: Column[Int]) = {
  myTable
    .filter(_.validFrom >= psqlNow)
    .filter(_.validUntil <= psqlNow)
    .filter(_.fakeId === limiter).map(e => (e.fakeId, e.name)
}
```

And I also want to change the following to lifted **Slick**, can I do it with **SimpleLiteral** (to somehow put **'count(*) OVER() recordsFiltered'** into the generated query?

```
SELECT *, count(*) OVER() recordsFiltered FROM example
WHERE id = $1
```

The examples are trivial, the actual code is a series of folds over filtering criteria.

Comment: You just need to find the right type for the nullary to work I imagine. are you using PgDate2Support or PgDateSupport? I notice the former uses LocalDate for the date data type.

Comment: @ivan-meredith Just the vanilla classes that come with slick-2.1.

And the question is more general, because `SimpleLiteral` takes a `Type` argument while `SimpleFunction` follows the normal Scala generic type syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import scala.slick.ast.TypedType

val current_date = Column.forNode[java.sql.Date](new SimpleLiteral("CURRENT_DATE")(implicitly[TypedType[java.sql.Date]]))
```

does the trick. Better support is missing at the moment.

I added a PR, so in Slick 2.2 it will be supported like this:

```
val current_date = SimpleLiteral[java.sql.Date]("CURRENT_DATE")
```

See https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/981